# VB6 "Provider cannot be found."

Tags: vb6, odbc, sql-server-native-client

I have a few applications written in VB6 that are all using the same connection string on the same machine. They are using the ODBC provider with the SQL Server Native Client 10.0 driver and connecting with explicit username and password.

At run-time, one of the applications throws an exception when I try to connect to the database:

3706: Provider cannot be found. It may not be properly installed.

I don't understand why this one application is having an issue when the others are working fine. The references are the same, down to the version number.

Comment: You'll have to provide more details.  Are you really using the MSDASQL Provider with an ODBC driver (if so, why?) or the actual OLEDB Provider SQLNCLI10.1?

Comment: They're all legacy applications and I just took them over less than a month ago, so I haven't had time to rewrite much yet. I went with the existing connection strings because in all of the others, they work fine, and working in a largely Windows Embedded environment, I try to change as little as possible before consulting our OS/hardware guy. I did find that removing the driver declaration fixes the issue; although I find that confusing, because doesn't it then use ODBC with SQL Native Client 10.0 anyway?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the connection string.  People do a lot of things that force ADO and the Provider to make guesses about what you're asking for.  It has to do with defaults at various levels as far as I know.  Using ODBC forces you to use at least 4 layers of software when ADO is your connector technology of choice, using OLEDB cuts this to 3.  I'm assuming ADO of course, you might be using something else (DAO/RDO?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing [MDAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Data_Access_Components) on your machine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the program on another system and using Access you will need to download and install http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23734 if access is not installed on the system